# How To Get Reliable Date With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, date, time

This past week I was faced with an interesting problem at work. I was faced with the necessity to get a date reliably using JavaScript. The existing code I was working with used new Date() to get the current date and time. However, I found that some of our customers had their system time/date that did not reflect the actual time/date.

THE GOOD SOLLUTION:

The best solution to this problem would be to figure out what date it was on the server side, and either push that to the front end via the templating language, or just set the pickup date on the server side after submission. Unfortunately this is not possible with our hosting service since there is no real backend access.

THE WORKING SOLUTION:

After researching the problem for some time, and finding nothing that would work for me, I came up with my own solution with works quite well. 
The idea is to send out an ajax request to some known secure site that returns very little data(or even returns a 404 error as we will see later). We can then use this responses header to get the accurate date (assuming the server’s date/time is correct). 
Here is what that looks like:

```
$.ajax({
url:’www.google.com’,
type:’get’,
success(data, status, xhr){
    return xhr.getResponseHeader(‘date’);
}
});
```

We can also easily add an error function that still returns the date if the request results in an error (like the 404 error I spoke of earlier):

```
...error:function(xhr, status, error){return xhr.getResponseHeader(‘date’); }
```

Since this function likes to return before the ajax request returns, it is safest to return a callback so that the function waits for the ajax call to finish. 
The final solution looks something like this:

```
Function getRealTime(callback){
$.ajax({
url:’www.google.com’,
type:’head’,
success(data, status, xhr){
    return callback(new Date(xhr.getResponseHeader(‘date’)));
},
error:function(xhr, status, error){
    return callback(new Date(xhr.getResponseHeader(‘date’)));
}
});
}
```

You will notice I changed the type to “head” which will result in only the headers of the response, cutting down the response size quite a bit. I also changed the return type to new Date() which will ensure that the function returns a Date object instead of a string, which I like better.

CONCLUSION:

This is a really simple and pretty fast way of getting a reliable date (and time if you so wish...time would be reliable down to a second or two). All the suggestions I saw online talked about requesting webpages with clocks on them and then parsing the time out, or even writing handlers for NIST servers to get the time like windows does, which would take quite a bit of development. As long as you make sure you are using a web page that is reliable (like a page on your own domain), and make sure the requests will not get out of hand and bog down the server (maybe think about pointing to a page that doesn’t exist on a domain that does to force a 404 error), you should be fine. For reference, my request using a page on my own webpage was 1.5kb over 200-ish milliseconds. Not bad for no optimization.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to optimize this would be to set up a page specifically for this that is empty. You could, if the requests got out of hand, even set up a separate server specifically for this purpose. However, if you are getting enough requests to bog down your servers, you should really invest in re-writing your site to use templates that can auto-fill the date for you.